The difference between Update and Attach
When the Attach method exists, where are we forced to use the Update method?
For example
public void UpdateStudent(Student student)
{
    var student = _context.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == student.Id);
    student.FullName = student.FullName;
    student.Age = student.Age;

    context.Students.Update(student); //or context.Students.Attach(student) ?

    context.SaveChanges();
}



Do not call Update if entity already tracked (as in your example). EF Core automatically tracks changes. Otherwise all fileds will be updated in database, which is not performant.

You're never forced to use the Update method. When to use it is a question of opinion.

Attach begins tracking the given entity and entries reachable from the given entity but will start its state as Unchanged even if you object is different from that of the one in the database.
Update will do the same thing, but starts with a state of Modified.
var entity = context.Students.Attach(student);
entity.State = EntityState.Modified;

is the same as
context.Students.Update(student);

In your example if you do attach after making the changes the SaveChanges call will not result in any changes being saved to the database as no changes were made after attaching. You would have to attach, and then make changes.

Not entirely right. Update may also mark an entity object as Added.

@GertArnold only if you have not set a primary key value

"For entity types with generated keys if an entity has its primary key value set then it will be tracked in the EntityState.Modified state. If the primary key value is not set then it will be tracked in the EntityState.Added state."

Yeah, I know, but for later visitors reading this it wouldn't harm to indicate that difference. If they read "a = b" they will think "a = always b".

For a start, in your example by default you do not need, and should not use Update. Your example has a typo as you are either re-assigning the student variable or declaring a duplicate named instance which would be a compiler error, but fixing that, this is all that is needed:
public void UpdateStudent(Student student)
{
    var existingStudent = _context.Students.First(s => s.Id == student.Id);
    existingStudent.FullName = student.FullName;
    existingStudent.Age = student.Age;

    context.SaveChanges();
}

This is a "safer" way to update data. When you read an entity from the DbContext, by default it will track changes. We read the current row (avoid "OrDefault" unless you are prepared to handle the possibility that a row won't be returned) we copy only the values that are allowed to change, then call SaveChanges. That tracked copy will have any changes written.
An example using Update:
public void UpdateStudent(Student student)
{
    context.Update(student);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

At face value this looks simpler, and for the most part it will work as expected but it has a few notable differences to the first approach. The first issue is that Update will generate an SQL UPDATE statement for the row for every single column in the entity whether they have been changed or not. Using the first approach an UPDATE statement will only be generated for the values that actually change, and if no value changes no UPDATE statement is run. So if the name and age were identical to what was just read, no database call to update the values gets called. Using Update() creates a few potential problems. Firstly the copy passed in could be stale or otherwise invalid, having changes to values you don't intend to ever change. Calling Update() will overwrite anything and everything in the row.
Attach() is a bit of a special case for dealing with untracked entities. Often you will see examples like:
public void UpdateStudent(Student student)
{
    context.Attach(student);
    context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}

That is effectively the same as just calling Update(student) and has the same vulnerabilities. You could modify your example to be a bit more safe using Attach to ensure only name and age are updated:
public void UpdateStudent(Student student)
{
    context.Attach(student);
    context.Entry(student).Property("Name").IsModified = true;
    context.Entry(student).Property("Age").IsModified = true;
    context.SaveChanges();
}

This ensures only the name and age are updated, but it will create an UPDATE statement regardless of whether the values actually changed or not.
Where something like Attach is more commonly used is to simplify operations where you want to link or delete data without first reading that data from the database. For instance if we had a method called DeleteStudent, we could pass a StudentId rather than an entire detached student record.
public void DeleteStudent(int studentId)
{
    var student = new Student(Id = studentId);
    context.Attach(student);
    context.Students.Remove(student);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

The "student" instance here isn't read from the DB and doesn't represent a complete student, but by attaching it, it can serve as a representation to a row in the database. You can use a similar approach to create stand-in references to attach/associate rows, but just remember that the attached instance will only be as complete as you populate and does not necessarily represent the actual complete or current data state in the database.
That is a very basic, and unsafe example. Typically we would first ensure the user calling this method actually has permissions to delete students and/or the particular student. We should also always check a DbContext instance that isn't created specifically for the operation for an existing tracked reference first:
    var student = context.Students.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == studentId);
    if (student == null)
    {
        student = new Student(Id = studentId);
        context.Attach(student);
    }
    context.Students.Remove(student);
    context.SaveChanges();

Checking .Local does not go to the database, it just checks the DbContext's tracking cache. If you call Attach or Update on a new untracked instance and the DbContext happens to already be tracking an instance with that same PK you will get an error. (Along the lines of "The DbContext is already tracking an instance...")
Overall, my recommendation is to use the first approach, and instead of passing around a student entity, pass something that represents only the information needed to perform the update so that it isn't confused with being an up-to-date representation.
That should hopefully be a fairly complete rundown of the use of Update and Attach with some things to consider if using them.

Just as in the other answer you don't mention that Update may also mark an entity object as Added. Also, Update on an already attached instance does not throw an exception.
